# Permalinks no longer working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a nightmare scenario where -- just getting ready to launch a site -- permalinks are suddenly not working and it breaks CSS and can't find PHP templates. I have the permalink structure set to "http://domain.org/%postname%-by-%author%/" but when I click on a post the permalink only calls postname, for example: http://domain.org/%postname%

My host provider checked the htaccess file and can't find any problem. I can't see one either. I have searched around and see many Wordpress users having permalink problems but they all seem to have different solutions. I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you get it working locally? Are there any errors in the Apache logs on the remote server?

Comment: You might try setting WP_DEBUG to 'true' in wp-config.php and check the messages if any

Answer (score 0):

Click update permalinks after moving worspress. Should fix you issue :) Usually in the database the old structure is saved and the new one doesn't work, even if your htacess is ok you should still hit the update permalinks button :)

If that doesn't work try debugging with http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/

:)

I am curios why is the css broken. That doesn't depend on whether your permalinks are broken or not. :-S

Have you installed any plugins before it failed?